# QSqlTableModel working with filter

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QSqlTableModel` that has 3 columns that I want to filter. Sometimes I want to filter on one of the columns, sometimes on all 3 columns and then only on two.

I cannot show any code as i have not written any. I am thinking on using a string, which is plug on the `model->setFilter()` function, that depending on the button pressed adds or take out parts of this string to form the filter phrase. Is there something that I missed on the description of the `QSqlTableModel` that would do this more efficiently?

Comment: When you use setFilter () a new request will be made to the database, ie you will have to reload the model every time you use that function, this function would recommend you if you load parts of the database. But if you have already loaded the database completely I recommend using QSortFilterProxyModel as it will only filter the loaded model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i looked at QSort... and at first glance looks to involved for what i want to do. I'm making a function that returns the string for the model->filter() function depending on what is selected on a bunch of drop down menus. I think this is easier.